# Docker --mount throws: executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: docker, mount

Running:

```
docker run 6740371b6542 --mount
docker run 6740371b6542 --mount source=aws,target=/root/.aws/,readonly
```

both produce the same error:

```
container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"--mount\": executable file not found in $PATH"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"--mount\": executable file not found in $PATH".
```

Can someone explain how to mount a file/folder from the host into the docker container? It seems *--mount* is the current/latest [recommended way](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#choose-the--v-or-mount-flag) to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

switching the order of the parameters should resolve that problem 
`docker run --mount source=aws,target=/root/.aws/,readonly 6740371b6542`

docker run executes a command as its last parameter. the error you received was due to the container not knowing what the `--mount` command is

In the future if you want to run a command in a container dont forget to use bash if you want to preserve path variables

`docker run --mount source=aws,target=/root/.aws/,readonly 6740371b6542 /bin/bash -c mysql`